# National Insurance Number UK from abroad

Tags: national-id-number

I am a Polish citizen and currently UCL student. I will move to UK in next 2 weeks and I want to set up the appointment before moving there. Is it possible to do it now from Poland or I have to wait till I move in to London? I was trying to call different places, but whether they were busy or I've got the information that I have to call as soon as I move to UK.
Thank you for your help.